# How do I initialise a static List<T>?

Tags: java, collections, static, initialization

I can't seem to understand what is going wrong in this declaration

```
public static List<Vertex> vertices; 

// where Vertex is a class with a default constructor 

public static void main ( String [] arg ) throws IOException {
vertices = new List<Vertex>(); // eclipse complains
}
```

Where and how should i initialize this list.....
Due to this when I go on to add in the list it complains of null pointer exception..... Can anybody tell me what am i doing wrong....

Comment: It gives the following error " Cannot instantiate the type List<Vertex> "

Comment: Are you sure that compiles?  `List` is an interface and can't be instantiated.

Comment: (Obligatory comment that mutable statics are evil.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List is an abstract type that is extended and implemented by various types of lists.
Try the following:

```
    public static void main ( String [] arg ) throws IOException {
         vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

List is an interface and can not be instantinated. Use ArrayList or LinkedList instead.

```
vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
```

Answer (score 0):

A List is an interface. You need to use a class that implements List such as ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
```

`List` is an interface in Java, so you need to use one of its implementations.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 0):

`List` is no a class, but interface. As interface is not a full concrete implementation of anything it can be instantiated. You can do new only to not abstract classes. So try to instantiate `ArrayList` or another implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an implementation of a List, such as:

```
vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse complains because List can't be instantiated because it is an interface and not a concrete class.
You have 2 options here-

**Option1:**

```
public static List<Vertex> vertices; 

// where Vertex is a class with a default constructor 

public static void main ( String [] arg ) throws IOException {
vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>(); // eclipse does not complain
}
```

**Option2:**

```
public static List<Vertex> vertices=new ArrayList<Vertex>(); 

// where Vertex is a class with a default constructor 

public static void main ( String [] arg ) throws IOException {
v
}
```